# Build conditionally list avoiding mutations

Tags: scala, collections

Let's say I want to build list of Pizza's ingredients conditionally:

```
val ingredients = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer("tomatoes", "cheese")

if (!isVegetarian()) {
   ingredients += "Pepperoni"  
}

if (shouldBeSpicy()) {
   ingredients += "Jalapeno"
}

//etc
```

Is there functional way to build this array using immutable collections?

I thought about:

```
val ingredients = List("tomatoes", "cheese") ++ List(
    if (!isVegetarian()) Some("Pepperoni") else None,
    if (shouldBeSpicy()) Some("Jalapeno") else None
).flatten
```

but is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach is not bad. I would probably just stick with list:

```
val ingredients = 
  List("tomatoes", "cheese") ++
  List("Pepperoni", "Sausage").filter(_ => !isVegetarian) ++
  List("Jalapeno").filter(_ => shouldBeSpicy)
```

Which makes it easy to add more ingredients connected to a condition (see "Sausage" above)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible way that is closer to @Antot but IMHO is much simpler.

What is unclear in your original code is where `isVegetarian` and `shouldBeSpicy` actually come from. Here I assume that there is a `PizzaConf` class as following to provide those configuration settings

```
case class PizzaConf(isVegetarian: Boolean, shouldBeSpicy: Boolean)
```

Assuming this, I think the simplest way is to have a `allIngredients` of `List[(String, Function1[PizzaConf, Boolean])]` type i.e. one that stores ingredients and functions to check their corresponding availability. Given that `buildIngredients` becomes trivial:

```
val allIngredients: List[(String, Function1[PizzaConf, Boolean])] = List(
  ("Pepperoni", conf => conf.isVegetarian),
  ("Jalapeno", conf => conf.shouldBeSpicy)
)

def buildIngredients(pizzaConf: PizzaConf): List[String] = {
  allIngredients
    .filter(_._2(pizzaConf))
    .map(_._1)
}
```

or you can merge `filter` and `map` using `collect` as in following:

```
def buildIngredients(pizzaConf: PizzaConf): List[String] = 
  allIngredients.collect({ case (ing, cond) if cond(pizzaConf) => ing })
```

Answer (score 1):

You could start with the full list of ingredients and then filter out the ingredients not passing the conditions:

```
Set("tomatoes", "cheese", "Pepperoni", "Jalapeno")
  .filter {
    case "Pepperoni" => !isVegetarian;
    case "Jalapeno" => shouldBeSpicy; 
    case _ => true // ingredients by default
  }
```

which for:

```
val isVegetarian = true
val shouldBeSpicy = true
```

would return:

```
Set(tomatoes, cheese, Jalapeno)
```

Comment: Still looks like a lot of boilerplate :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by creating a sequence of predicates, which defines the conditions applied to filter the ingredients.

```
// available ingredients
val ingredients = Seq("tomatoes", "cheese", "ham", "mushrooms", "pepper", "salt")

// predicates
def isVegetarian(ingredient: String): Boolean = ingredient != "ham"

def isSpicy(ingredient: String): Boolean = ingredient == "pepper"

def isSalty(ingredient: String): Boolean = ingredient == "salt"

// to negate another predicate
def not(predicate: (String) => Boolean)(ingr: String): Boolean = !predicate(ingr)

// sequences of conditions for different pizzas:
val vegeterianSpicyPizza: Seq[(String) => Boolean] = Seq(isSpicy, isVegetarian)

val carnivoreSaltyNoSpices: Seq[(String) => Boolean] = Seq(not(isSpicy), isSalty)

// main function: builds a list of ingredients for specified conditions!
def buildIngredients(recipe: Seq[(String) => Boolean]): Seq[String] = {
  ingredients.filter(ingredient => recipe.exists(_(ingredient)))
}

println("veg spicy: " + buildIngredients(vegeterianSpicyPizza))
// veg spicy: List(tomatoes, cheese, mushrooms, pepper, salt)

println("carn salty: " + buildIngredients(carnivoreSaltyNoSpices))
// carn salty: List(tomatoes, cheese, ham, mushrooms, salt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by other answers, I came up with something like this:

```
case class If[T](conditions: (Boolean, T)*) {
  def andAlways(values: T*): List[T] =
    conditions.filter(_._1).map(_._2).toList ++ values
}
```

It could be used like:

```
val isVegetarian = false
val shouldBeSpicy = true

val ingredients = If(
   !isVegetarian -> "Pepperoni",
   shouldBeSpicy -> "Jalapeno",
).andAlways(
   "Cheese",
   "Tomatoes"
)
```

Still waiting for a better option :)

Answer (score 1):

If any ingredient will only need testing against one condition, you could do something like this:

```
val commonIngredients = List("Cheese", "Tomatoes")
val nonVegetarianIngredientsWanted = {
  if (!isVegetarian)
    List("Pepperoni")
  else
    List.empty
}
val spicyIngredientsWanted = {
  if (shouldBeSpicy)
    List("Jalapeno")
  else
    List.empty
}
val pizzaIngredients = commonIngredients ++ nonVegetarianIngredientsWanted ++ spicyIngredientsWanted
```

This doesn't work if you have ingredients which are tested in two categories: for example if you have spicy sausage then that should only be included if !isVegetarian and spicyIngredientsWanted.  One method of doing this would be to test both conditions together:

```
val (optionalIngredients) = {
  (nonVegetarianIngredientsWanted, spicyIngredientsWanted) match {
    case (false, false) => List.empty
    case (false, true) => List("Jalapeno")
    case (true, false) => List("Pepperoni")
    case (true, true) => List("Pepperoni, Jalapeno, Spicy Sausage")
}
val pizzaIngredients = commonIngredients ++ optionalIngredients
```

This can be extended to test any number of conditions, though of course the number of case arms needed extends exponentially with the number of conditions tested.